# android slider component to show page previews?

Tags: android

I have pages to show user next by next with a swipe gesture. I know there are plenty of magazine apps using a bottom slider for viewing all pages' previews and when a page tapped that page is shown to user. I need that bottom slider(what is it called I don't know). I guess there should be a component or tutorial showing how to do that, I would be pleased if someone can enlighten me?  [image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? It would make things easier. :)

Comment: I posted a screenshot. This should be a component, i see this in many apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a gallery view to me.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html